# Install4j silent upgrade without closing running application

Tags: java, install4j

With Install4j I am trying to do a silent upgrade without shutting down the app it is upgrading.  I am receiving the following error **"The application is running. Please close all instances and run this installer again.**"  Is there any way around this.  I am calling the installer from my code with the following code

```
String [] args = new String[1];
args[0] = "-q";
ApplicationLauncher.launchApplicationInProcess("6661", args, new ApplicationLauncher.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void exited(int i) {
                        logger.info("The installer exited");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void prepareShutdown() {
                        logger.info("Calling the prepareShutowon fuction");
                    }
                }, ApplicationLauncher.WindowMode.DIALOG, null);
```

This does not seem to work. The upgrade only works if I close the application which I do not want do.

Answer (score 0):

> With Install4j I am trying to do a silent upgrade without shutting down the app it is upgrading.

That is not possible, on Windows JAR files and executables cannot be overwritten if they are in use by a running executable.

In the updater, you need a "Shut down calling launcher" action just before the new installer is started. You have probably removed that action from the default configuration. The new installer can then restart the application automatically with an "Execute launcher" action on the "Finish" screen.

Comment: One way I got around this is to install my app in a sub-directory under a version number.  So it will be something like    "MyApp -> 1.0.0 ->AppFiles".  Now my upgrade will create a new subdirectory like "MyApp -> 2.0.0->AppFiles". @Ingo